# How to roll an image from right to left on web page load?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to roll this image right to left?

```css
img{
 position:absolute;
 top:50px;
 right:5px;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:#ff00ff;
 
}
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/15/28/zMTLik.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;"/>
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by 'roll'.

Comment: The answers below have been barely responded to, and the question has not been clarified, so I think this should be put on hold as "unclear".

Answer (score 2):

Check this snippet in CSS3 @keyframes rule

```css
img{
 position:absolute;
 top:50px;
 right:80%;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 border-radius:50%;
 transition-duration:1s;
 animation:animate 3s;
}

@keyframes animate{
  from{
  transform:rotate(0deg);
  } 
  to{
  transform:rotate(-500deg);
  }
  from{
  right:5px;
  } 
  to{
  right:80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/15/28/zMTLik.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;"/>
```

Comment: Nice But That Image Fixed At Left After Rolling .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using combination of keyframe animation. Working code below.

```css
#circle {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
 
 
  /* Animation to spin and move the sphere */
  -webkit-animation: spin 1000ms linear infinite, moveLeftToRight 5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 1000ms linear infinite, moveLeftToRight 5s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin 1000ms linear infinite, moveLeftToRight 5s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1000ms linear infinite, moveLeftToRight 5s linear infinite;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

/* Spinning the sphere using key frames */

@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg); }
}


/* Move sphere from left to right */

@keyframes moveLeftToRight {
  0%   { left: 0; }
  100% { left: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
<img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/15/28/zMTLik.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;"/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

- spin the earth  (background-position-x)
- move right to left  (right)

```css
#rotate {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top:50px;
  right:5px;
  background: url(http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/15/28/zMTLik.jpg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: visible;
  background-size: 210px;
  box-shadow: inset 16px 0 40px 6px rgb(0, 0, 0),
    inset -3px 0 6px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from { background-position-x: 0px; right:5px; }
  to { background-position-x: 210px; right:100%; }
}
```

```html
<div id="rotate">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
   
    position :relative;
    border-radius:50px;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {left: 80%;}

    100% {left: 0%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
   0%   {left:80%;}

    50% {left: 0%;}
 100% {left: 80%;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/15/28/zMTLik.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px;"/>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```